# Configuration Topology with cooja/contiky

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to implementing tree topology with Cooja/contiky. Finding through examples i've not been able to find an a good example to find what i need.
In short : 
I'd need to implementing a topology of this type(picture here under) with cooja end contiky, is there someone that could give me some advice?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really use Contiki Operating System, I have only ever used TinyOS but a network topology such as the one you have should be easily achievable.

For TinyOS, the mote-to-mote radio tutorial [HERE](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Mote-mote_radio_communication) will show you how to two different sensor nodes can communicate with each other (a gateway is basically just a sensor node connected to a PC) and the mote-to-PC communication tutorial [HERE](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Mote-PC_serial_communication_and_SerialForwarder_(TOS_2.1.1_and_later)) will show you how a gateway node can forward information from itself to the PC it is connected to. When the network is running you basically have a Java application listening to USB port and receiving packets from gateway node. Once the packet has been received on the Java application then you can send it to an external network server.

It may sound difficult if you have never developed on TinyOS but what you want to do is very common and so there will be complete programs in the tutorial section of a typical TinyOS distribution showing you how to achieve most of the things you need you need to achieve. There should also be similar examples in Contiki.